# how to enable Jetty debug log in 9.4.40

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am using Jetty 9.4.40 and for jetty debug logs I have added

```
        1.   -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog - 
              Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG
        
        2. import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;
           import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog;
           Log.setLog(new StdErrLog());
```

But Still getting exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCookie.getSameSiteDefault(HttpCookie.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.checkSameSite(Response.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.addCookie(Response.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.replaceCookie(Response.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getSession(Request.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getSession(Request.java:1602)
    at
```

I'm trying to set the logging level to DEBUG in a Jetty instance. It was working on previous versions and when we upgraded it to 9.4.40 it started failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Logging configuration.

See https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/6186

Your `HttpCookie` Logger is not configured by the time the offending code is run.

> ```
> -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
> -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG
> ```

This will work only on the initial JVM.  If your build or instance or configuration has something that forces a forked JVM, this won't be carried over to the forked JVM.

> ```java
> import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;
> import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog;
> Log.setLog(new StdErrLog());
> ```

This will work, but only if it's literally the very first thing you do in your program.

```java
// These are the ONLY two import statements with references
// to `org.eclipse.jetty` allowed in here, any other 
// import statements risk causing the logging to initialize
// before your efforts below kick in.
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Log.setLog(new StdErrLog());
    // the rest of your startup.
}
```

Because this is Logging, the configuration has to happen as early as possible, and be configured regardless of initialization / forking of
the JVM.

Do this instead.

Create a `jetty-logging.properties` and put it in your classpath somewhere, in the root of one of your classloader references (directory or jar) is all that's needed.

Since you said `embedded-jetty`, put in the root of your jar that has the Main-Class.

Contents of ...

```ini
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG
# You can even configure specific trees to be less noisy.
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCookie.LEVEL=INFO
```

Comment: Implemented above but now getting this Error                    Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Logger with name [org.eclipse.jetty.io.CyclicTimeout]
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.CyclicTimeout.<clinit>(CyclicTimeout.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.Session$SessionInactivityTimer.<init>(Session.java:117)

Comment: Added jetty-logging.properties file in classpath and getting above Error